# InvalidArgumentError when implementing variational autoencoder in keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to implement a variational autoencoder using Chollet's deep learning book as a reference. I'm having difficulty fitting the data to the model, the image shape is (512, 512, 3) however it's giving me the error that the shapes are incompatible. I'm wondering if the error is in the lambda layer implementing the variational loss, since the images I'm using are from a different dataset than in the book.

> InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [524288] vs. [1572864]
>      [[{{node custom_variational_layer_6/logistic_loss/mul}} =

I've tried adjusting the image shape, the number of channels, the reconstruction loss, and changed the mean function that averages the KL and cross entropy loss to a sum function of just the cross entropy loss, and nothing seems to work.

```
def create_encoder():
    input_img = Input(shape=img_shape)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(input_img)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', strides=(2, 2), activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu')(x)
    shape_before_flattening = K.int_shape(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
    z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)
    z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim)(x)
    model = Model(input_img, [z_mean, z_log_var])
    return model, shape_before_flattening

def sample(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    eps = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(z_mean)[0], latent_dim),
                         mean=0., stddev=1.)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var) * eps

encoder, shape_before_flattening = create_encoder()
input_img = encoder.inputs[0]
z_mean = encoder.outputs[0]
z_log_var = encoder.outputs[1]
z = layers.Lambda(sample)([z_mean, z_log_var])

def create_decoder():
    print(K.int_shape(z))
    decoder_input = Input(K.int_shape(z)[1:])
    x = layers.Dense(np.prod(shape_before_flattening[1:]),
                     activation='relu')(decoder_input)
    x = layers.Reshape(shape_before_flattening[1:])(x)
    x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3,
                               padding='same',
                               activation='relu',
                               strides=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Conv2D(1, 3,
                      padding='same',
                      activation='sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(decoder_input, x)
    return model

class CustomVariationalLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def vae_loss(self, x, z_decoded): 
        x = K.flatten(x)
        z_decoded = K.flatten(z_decoded)
        xent_loss = keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(x, z_decoded)
        kl_loss = -5e-4 * K.mean(
            1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1) 
        print(K.int_shape(xent_loss))
        print(K.int_shape(kl_loss))
        #return K.mean(mse_loss + kl_loss)
        return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_loss)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = inputs[0]
        z_decoded = inputs[1]
        loss = self.vae_loss(x, z_decoded)
        self.add_loss(loss, inputs=inputs)
        return x

decoder = create_decoder()
z_decoded = decoder(z)
out = CustomVariationalLayer()([input_img, z_decoded])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
print("X train shape ", X_train.shape)
print("X test shape ", X_test.shape)

vae = Model(input_img, out)
vae.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss=None)
vae.summary()
vae.fit(x=X_train, y=None, shuffle=True, epochs=10, batch_size=batch_size)
```

I expect it to train the model and not produce an error.